# php artisan make:notification command is not woking

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to implement notification in laravel 5.3 by using `php artisan make:notification post` command but but it showing

> make:notification is not defined

here the snapshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HObcF.png

so how can i solve this ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see 'make:notification' when you run: php artisan ?

Comment: No. even i can'nt see make:notification command by running php artisan list command @JonHockley

Comment: which laravel version you are using ? check in composer.json ?

Comment: @PradyutManna you can double check your version by running: php artisan --version

Comment: at first it was 5.2.* but then i edit with 5.3.* and run composer update.but by running php artisan -- version still showing 5.2.45

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: so you don't have laravel 5.3 installed and trying to run commands of laravel 5.3.

Comment: i am using php version 5.5.30 @Rishi

Comment: You must have `PHP >= 5.6.4` to install laravel 5.3 check : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation

Comment: It looks like you haven't completely upgraded from 5.2.x to 5.3.   I would suggest consulting the upgrade guides on the Laravel documentation.